# NotificationCenter addObserver(observer:selector:name:object) -- what is object?

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I am having trouble understanding what the `object` parameter is in  `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer:selector:name:object)`

If I understand it correctly, it acts as a kind of filter; only notifications posted from this object will be observed. But I can't seem to actually figure out how to use it.

I created a class and made a global instance of it

```
class FooClass {
    func postNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("TestNotification"), object: self)
    }
}

let globalFoo = FooClass()
```

Then in my first ViewController I press a button which calls `globalFoo.postNotification()`

Then in my second ViewController I registered like so:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationReceived), name: NSNotification.Name("TestNotification"), object: globalFoo)

    }

    func notificationReceived() {
        print("notification received")
    }

}
```

It works fine when I don't specify `object` (i.e. nil), so clearly I'm misunderstanding what it is.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Instead of editing your question to show the answer, simply accept an answer (as you have).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `object` parameter used when posting a notification is to indicate what object is actually posting the notification.

When adding an observer, you can leave `object` nil and you will get all of the named notifications regardless of which object actually sent the notification. Or you can specify a specific object when adding an observer and you will then only be notified when that specific object posts the named notification.

Comment: Hmm...that's what I though I was doing when I specified globalFoo as the sender and receiver.

Comment: Make sure the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller is called before you call `postNotification` on the instance of `FooClass`.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. It works as expected. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Some notifications use this parameter to provide more appropriate information to the `observer`.

For example, notifications like `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` optionally accepts `NSManagedObjectContext` object so that it can notify changes only from that context.

Comment: Right, that's what I understood from reading the docs. But then why doesn't it work in the example I gave above when I specify the same global object as the sender and receiver?